# Error while executing aws eks commands on aws-cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

successfully installed the EKS CLI [image: version of EKS] on the terminal. But when I try to execute the command

```
aws eks --us-east-1 region update-kubeconfig --name codefresh
```

it showing an error saying [image: error image]

```
aws: error: argument command: Invalid choice
```

It would be great if someone helps me with the proper solution.

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in your call. You specify region with `--region us-east-1` and not with `--us-east-1 region`